# Scrolling Navigation gets stuck in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, scroll

I have a navigation in the top right corner that will scroll down a page with a user.  I am using this jQuery code:

```
var $scrollingDiv = $("#scrollingDiv");
    $(window).scroll(function(){            
        $scrollingDiv
            .stop()
            .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"}, "fast" );  

    });
```

the CSS:

```
#scrollingDiv{background-color:#fff;margin-left:4%;margin-top:10px;padding:0 2% 2%;}
```

It works great, the Problem is:
The navigation filters the content, so you can be at the bottom of the page, click on a link in the navigation and it will filter the content so there will only be 2 paragraphs instead of 20.  The scrolling navigation will get STUCK on the bottom in IE.  Other browsers it moves back to the top.

I tried using a

```
<a name="top"> </a>
```

But that didnt work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

here is what you do:

```
$("a.nav").click(function () {
    $("#scrollingDiv").css({marginTop: '10px'}); 
    });
```

This will reset the marginTop so it won't get stuck on the bottom